# Parallel.For combined with ConcurrentBag seems not to be thread-safe

Tags: thread-safety, parallel.for

first time I use Parallel.For to fill Lists (here ConcurrentBag)
But it seems that the ConcurrentBag receives data from the other threads.
I have a huge amount of data in xSource an the task is to distribute it to several Lists.
What ist wrong here?

```
public static void getNearXvalues(double deltaX, double xCenter, double[] xSource, out double[] xNear)
{
    var xList = new ConcurrentBag<double>();

    Parallel.For(0, xSource.Length, i =>
    {
        if((Mat.Abs(xCenter-xSource)<deltaX)
        {
            xList.Add(xSource[i]);
        }
    });
    xNear = xList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, didn't had time to investigate, I used Semaphore to solve the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0